# Gave User Read Only Permission In Sharing Setting but Able to Edit Records when OWD is Private

Tags: permissions, security, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I want a user to see all the records of Quote object of other users based on some criteria, I created a sharing rule on the opportunity to share records with that user and gave read-only permission but the user can edit them also. I checked the permission sets also but there were not any. So, I am confused here .
The permission is as below :

- The OWD setting on Opportunity is Private
- Opportunity for User Profile is: Create, Edit, Delete, Read

Did I miss something ?

FYI: I recreated the same sharing rule in my sandbox which is working fine but not in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record on which I was checking was already "manually shared" to the user so the user had the edit permission for that record.

I got the solution from the [Answer to the other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44746/contact-visible-with-owd-private-even-though-user-doesnt-have-access?rq=1). in Which @sfdcfox explained in detail.