# Able to view the Account records even though OWD set to private and removed all permissions like view all & modify all

Tags: apex, security, sharing-rule, owd, criteria-based-sharing

I have created the sharing rule to share ony specific record type record to shared with a group.

my object is `Account` and Org-Wide Defaults set to the Private, removed the permissions like `view all` & `modify all` via profile , permission set but still user is able to view the records which is not sharing.

Any help is much appreciated on this.[image]

Comment: Check this thread out - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44746/contact-visible-with-owd-private-even-though-user-doesnt-have-access?rq=1

Comment: It may be due to [Implicit Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sharing_across_objects.htm&type=5): if they have access to an account’s child record, they have implicit Read Only access to that account.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick help. got the issue and i missed the below point while implementing the rule.
@RubenDG : Thank you , u are correct and it is helpful
**IF that user happens to own an Opportunity related to Account OR part of Opportunity sales team.. then that user gains implicit sharing access to Account with access as "Read only" and rest of object access will be false. It kind of falls in line with how your screenshot is. Help check**